# Project Not showing icons after Executeable jar file

Tags: java, swing

I am running net beans application, when i run it via net beans it is showing icons properly...but when i convert it to executable .exe it is not showing icons..i did a lot of research to solve this problem but everything gone in vain. This is the best method i have saw to get icons dynamically....
My icon heraricy is src/com/idoccsmain/icons/ and all of my icons inside the "icons" folder

```
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Main.Class.getClass().getResource("/com/idoccsmain/icons/"+"add_icon.p‌​ng")
```

through this line i am getting all of my different icons..can any one suggest any solution for me....?

Comment: Check whether the icons really added to the .jar

Comment: have you tried ?? if your problem resolved then accept this answer.

Comment: Please create a small, stand-alone program which illustrates your problem and post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks guys for responses with your help i came up with this... solution
put images in Src folder e.g src/icons/ and inside icons folder.[image]

Than use this line in netbeans to get your images working......

```
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/AnyIconName.png"));
```

and make sure use this line for each icon.

Comment: This polutes the src directory with non-source files. A cleaner solution (IMO) is to modify the `build.xml` file to override an appropriate target (I think it's called `-pre-build`) to copy the icons into the build directory so that they will be included in your jar file.

Answer (score 1):

**For J2ME Application**

[image]

Check this image carefully, **Right Click** on project then **Properties**.

Select **Application Descriptor** and then select **MIDlets**

If it is showing anything there, like showing in this picture then edit accordingly.

**NOTE : -** In the above scenario `src/myproject/` where `icon` and `.java` exist.

**===== UPDATE =====**

**Desktop based executable jar**

Then use, this code

```
this.getFrame().setIconImage(new imageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("add_icon.p‌​ng")));
```

**Note:** this line only works if the images are in the root of the jar file. If not, you have to specify the folder on the string:

```
getResource("yourfolder/add_icon.p‌​ng")
```

You might also interested for this [link](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/features.php) to create executable java file and also associate icon to it.

Comment: Thanks for our effort but brother i am using net beans 7.2.1 and there is nowhere this option you specified "Application Descriptor" in properties of project..?

Comment: is this mobile application ??

Comment: No no it is desktop application.Sorry it was mistake in my question it is .exe file

Comment: i am trying but when i use getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/Idoccs/icons/"+"add_icon.png");
it is giving me error...and if i remove getClassLoader() than it is saying ok..secondly i am trying to make .exe with jsmooth...than will leave comment..

Comment: and i have tried AdvanceInstaller with the getClass().getResource(..). it did't work..

Comment: there should be location problem. I would say, better to put you icon in same directory without creating different directory.

Comment: same directory means inside src folder?

Comment: yes, i mean, with your project `.java` file and follow my first code by only specifying the name of your icon.